# Angular 2 and the function $interval

Tags: dart, angular, carousel, settimeout, setinterval

How I can rewrite in Angular2 and Dart this code in angular1:

```
$interval(function () {
    if($scope.carouselIndex < $scope.showcases.length -1){
      $scope.carouselIndex = $scope.carouselIndex + 1;
    } else {
      $scope.carouselIndex = 0;
    }

  }, properties.delay);
```

I've tried in this way but didn't work:

```
 carouselIndex = 0;
          for(int i=0; i<contents.size(); i++){
            if(carouselIndex < contents.length -1){
              setTimeout(function() {
              carouselIndex = carouselIndex + 1;
              }, 1000);
            } else {
              carouselIndex = 0;
            }
      }
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `Observable.interval` method:

```
Observable.interval(properties.delay).subscribe(() => {
  if (this.carouselIndex < this.showcases.length - 1) {
    this.carouselIndex = this.carouselIndex + 1;
  } else {
    this.carouselIndex = 0;
  }
});
```

An event will be triggered each time the delay is reached. So the callback defined when subscribing will be called accordingly.

In your case, you tried to mix a synchronous loop with asynchronous processing with the `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Timer` class for this:

```
  Timer _timer;

  someFunc() {
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000 /*properties.delay*/),
        (_) {
      if (this.carouselIndex < this.showcases.length - 1) {
        this.carouselIndex = this.carouselIndex + 1;
      } else {
        this.carouselIndex = 0;
      }
    });

    // to stop the periodic execution use
    // _timer.cancel();
  }
```